# Apache setup on Eclipse PHP (Ubuntu 10.10)

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, eclipse-pdt

Have a basic question on running PHP applications using Eclipse PHP on Ubuntu. I have installed Apache2 and it has its DocumentRoot setup to /var/www. Now my eclipse workspace points to /home/me/workspace. How do I deploy my applications from my workspace folder to the server using Eclipse ? 
        If I choose my workspace loc as /var/www, things work. But I dont wanna do that. Is there a way I can publish my code to the server ?I remember the Tomcat plugin for eclipse had a 'publish to server' feature. Anything similar on Eclipse PHP ?

Also, not sure if I have missed out on anything while setting things up..

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing it the other way around, setting the apache docroot to your workspace dir? I work with ZendStudio (Eclipse based) with this setup.

Comment: Hi AJweb.. thanks for your comment.. I did think about that. But its just that I wanna keep my dev and prod env separate. I am currently doing it through ANT as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747070/eclipse-pdt-how-do-i-get-the-files-on-the-server .